# writing json data incremently into a file using jsoncpp

Tags: c++, json, jsoncpp

I am using jsoncpp to write the data into json format like following:

```
Json::Value event;   
Json::Value lep(Json::arrayValue);

event["Lepton"] = lep;
lep.append(Json::Value(1));
lep.append(Json::Value(2));
lep.append(Json::Value(3));
lep.append(Json::Value(4));

event["Lepton"] = lep;
Json::StyledWriter styledWriter;
cout << styledWriter.write(event);
```

I got the following output:

```
{
   "Lepton" : [
      1,
      2,
      3,
      4
   ]
}
```

I want to write multiple such blocks into my data files. What I eventually want is following:

```
[
    {
       "Lepton" : [
          1,
          2,
          3,
          4
       ]
    },
    {
       "Lepton" : [
          1,
          2,
          3,
          4
       ]
    }
]
```

Currently, I am writing `[` and then the json entries followed by a `,` and finally at the end `]`. Also I have to remove the last `,` in the final data file.

Is there a way to do all this automatically by jsoncpp or by other means?

Thanks

Comment: Is the output you show the *actual* output of the code you show? Or is it the *expected* output? Please show us *both*.

Comment: just added the desired output.

Comment: Then you need an *outer* array, where you add multiple `event` objects, and write the outer array object.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks for the clue. Let me try it out.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have included a code based on your suggestion in the answer below. I hope that it is fine with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the suggestion from @Some prorammer dude in the comments section, I did the following:

```
   Json::Value AllEvents(Json::arrayValue);
   for(int entry = 1; entry < 3; ++entry)
   {
      Json::Value event;   
      Json::Value lep(Json::arrayValue); 

      lep.append(Json::Value(1 + entry));
      lep.append(Json::Value(2 + entry));
      lep.append(Json::Value(3 + entry));
      lep.append(Json::Value(4 + entry));

      event["Lepton"] = lep;
      AllEvents.append(event);

      Json::StyledWriter styledWriter;
      cout << styledWriter.write(AllEvents);
   }
```

I got the desired output as shown below:

```
    [
        {
           "Lepton" : [
              1,
              2,
              3,
              4
           ]
        },
        {
           "Lepton" : [
              2,
              3,
              4,
              5
           ]
        }
    ]
```

Basically, I created a Json array and appended the resulting Json objects into it.